# Getting "cannot find -lmysqlclient" when trying to install python mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, pip, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm trying to install the mysqlclient module in a virtual environment on RHEL with Percona clustering running a Mysql db.

Each time it exits with this error

> gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -g
>   build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64
>
> -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>
> /bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I believe I have the library installed here:

> $ ls /usr/lib64/mysql/
>
> libmysqlclient.a
>
> libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0
>
> libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
>
> libperconaserverclient.a
>
> libmysqlclient_r.a
>
> libmysqlclient.so.18
>
> libmysqlservices.a
>
> libperconaserverclient_r.a

So I'm not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to explicitly pass the library path to gcc like this

```
sudo pip3 install mysqlclient --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/lib64/mysql/"
```